# RuntimeError: Failed to parse Dictionary from the input stream

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection, cntk, faster-rcnn

I'm completely new to cntk. I recently installed cntk 2.7 (GPU version) on my pc (windows 10,i5-7200U CPU) with GeForce 940MX GPU. I'm trying to set up cntk and the faster rcnn object-detection example provided in the link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/object-detection-using-faster-r-cnn

I'm trying to run the toy example.

After running the install_data_and_model.py in Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN folder

I run the run_faster_rcnn.py Examples/Image/Detection/FasterRCNN folder

I get the following error:

```
Selected GPU[0] GeForce 940MX as the process wide default device.

About to throw exception 'Failed to parse Dictionary from the input stream.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_faster_rcnn.py", line 34, in 
trained_model = train_faster_rcnn(cfg)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FasterRCNN\FasterRCNN_train.py", line 291, in train_faster_rcnn
eval_model = train_faster_rcnn_e2e(cfg)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FasterRCNN\FasterRCNN_train.py", line 314, in train_faster_rcnn_e2e
loss, pred_error = create_faster_rcnn_model(image_input, roi_input, dims_node, cfg)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FasterRCNN\FasterRCNN_train.py", line 177, in create_faster_rcnn_model
base_model = load_model(cfg['BASE_MODEL_PATH'])

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\internal\swig_helper.py", line 69, in wrapper
result = f(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\functions.py", line 1721, in load_model
return Function.load(model, device, format)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\internal\swig_helper.py", line 69, in wrapper
result = f(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\HP-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\ops\functions.py", line 1635, in load
return cntk_py.Function.load(str(model), device, format.value)

RuntimeError: Failed to parse Dictionary from the input stream.


[CALL STACK]
> CNTK::Internal:: UseSparseGradientAggregationInDataParallelSGD

- CNTK::operator>>

- CNTK::Function:: Load

- PyInit__cntk_py (x2)

- PyCFunction_Call

- PyEval_GetFuncDesc

- PyEval_EvalFrameEx (x2)

- PyFunction_SetAnnotations

- PyObject_Call

- PyEval_GetFuncDesc

- PyEval_EvalFrameEx (x2)

- PyEval_GetFuncDesc (x2)
```

Can someone help me with what the issue is all about?

Answer (score 0):

This error always happen when you shutdown cntk when last model was saving,so the model file break